# ASP.NET Core Identity 2 usermanager CreateAsync never seems to finish

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity, asp.net-core-identity

I am using Identity for my ASP.NET Core 2 project. And while I have been sort of pleased with it as i find out more about it, yet i run into an issue, and i can not seem to figure out what is going wrong here. The code looks like so:

```
public class UserNewViewModel
{
    public UserNewViewModel()
    {

    }
    public UserNewViewModel(Domain.User user)
    {
        NormalizedEmail = user.NormalizedEmail;
        UserName = user.UserName;
        Password = string.Empty;
        Email = user.Email;
        FirstName = user.FirstName;
        LastName = user.LastName;
    }
    public string NormalizedEmail { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    /*[Required]
    [MinLength(8)]*/
    public string Password { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [EmailAddress]
    public string Email { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string Disabled { get; set; }
}
```

is sent into:

```
[HttpPost]
    //[AllowAnonymous]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<IActionResult> RegisterUser(ViewModels.UserNewViewModel model)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(model.UserName))
            {
                model.UserName = model.Email;
            }
            var existingUser = _BygBookDataContext.Users.FirstOrDefault(u => u.NormalizedEmail.Equals(model.NormalizedEmail));
            if(existingUser == null)
            {
                existingUser = new Domain.User(){
                        UserName = model.UserName,
                        Email = model.Email                     
                    };

                var result = await _userManager.CreateAsync(existingUser, model.Password);
if(result.Success)
{

}

            }
            else
            {
                existingUser.UserName = model.UserName;
                existingUser.FirstName = model.FirstName;
                existingUser.LastName = model.LastName;
                existingUser.Email = model.Email;

                await _userManager.UpdateAsync(existingUser);

                _BygBookDataContext.SaveChanges();

                if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(model.Password))
                {
                    var pwToken = await _userManager.GeneratePasswordResetTokenAsync(existingUser);

                    await _userManager.ResetPasswordAsync(existingUser, pwToken, model.Password);

                    _BygBookDataContext.SaveChanges();
                }
            }


            return PartialView("UserNewPartial", existingUser);
        }

        // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
        return PartialView(model);
    }
```

The culprit as far as I am concerned is this line:

```
await _userManager.CreateAsync(existingUser, model.Password);
```

I can not figure out where this goes wrong. I have tried doing something similar in other places of my code:

```
await userMan.CreateAsync(new Domain.User{
                            UserName = "teknik@bygbook.dk",
                            Email = "teknik@bygbook.dk",
                            FirstName ="Teknik",
                            LastName = string.Empty,
                            EmailConfirmed = true
                        },
                        adminPassword);
```

So am at a point of considering if the problem could be that the existingUser is initialised by loading it from the database, but that does seem unlikely as a null value can hardly be tracked by EF.

can anyone tell me what is going wrong for me here?

EDIT:  Even when putting it into a variable and setting a break point at `if(result.success)` it never breaks there, it just seems stuck waiting for the createAsync

Comment: What is the exact "issue"? Are you getting an exception?

Comment: What's the result of `await _userManager.CreateAsync(existingUser, model.Password);`? The devs didn't implement a `IdentityResult` return type just for fun for you to ignore. You should check if it succeeds and on failure look into the error properties why it failed. Almost all methods of user manager and identity will return an `IdentityResult`

Comment: If you don't inspect the result its like doing a try block with an empty catch ;) You probably have the user already created or your password violates the policy, but youll only find out when you inspect the resulting `IdentityResult` object

Comment: Edited the question.

Comment: If you look at the edit i made. I try to use the debugger to watch the result of `userManager.CreateAsync` but the thing is if i do `if(result.Success)` or `if(!result.Success)` the debugger will never get to that point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, like an idiot, I did not check whether the `model.Password` actually had a value. It didn't. I still wonder why `userManager.CreateAsync(user, null)` did not throw an exception or give any errors or anything, but there you go.

The flaw was my input which was basically `<input type="password" name="Email" />` so when i set the attributes value to 'password' instead, it worked like a charm. Sorry for taking up your time.